# Does ActionMailer's "enable_starttls_auto" setting protect my email credentials when communicating with Gmail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, security, actionmailer

I am interested in using Rails’ ActionMailer to send emails through a gmail account to users.  There are a number of tutorials out there that suggest the following setup, which does the basic job:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :user_name            => "my-gmail-address@gmail.com",
  :password             => "my-gmail-password",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

My concern, however, is security. Gmail requires that I downgrade the security settings on the gmail account to make this method work, plus, [presumably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278983/why-is-authentication-plain-the-default-setting-for-actionmailer-in-rails-wi), ActionMailer sends my email credentials to Gmail using nothing but BASE64 encoding, which is easy to decode.

That said, ActionMailer's “enable_starttls_auto” setting gives me some hope that ActionMailer and Gmail will perform a secure handshake before the email credentials are exchanged and a safe channel will be established for the credentials to pass through. Is this the case and can I rest easy, or to really establish a secure connection here will I need to communicate with gmail via some kind of an OAuth 2 API connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting "enable_starttls_auto" to true would check if the server supports starttls and use it **if** it does. However, **secure transport is not guaranteed** in case of an arbitrary smtp server: your credentials will be sent practically plaintext, should the server not support starttls.

Whether you trust GMail to always have starttls enabled is your choice.

If you want to make sure, you could use ssl: true and port: 465, which should also be supported by GMail servers if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thank you. Do you happen to know how to determine whether the email communicated from my localhost development machine to the Gmail server utilized TLS? When I look at the sent message on the Gmail account, and "show original", it says TLS in the header (it says this regardless of whether 'enable_starttls_auto' is enabled), but I'm not sure this represents the communication I am interested in, or whether it represents the email that was sent from the Gmail server to the email recipient - I suspect the latter.

Comment: I think enable_starttls_auto is enabled by default, so if the server supports starttls, emails will be sent over TLS. That may have happened to your emails too, I think they would not have TLS headers if they were sent plaintext, but I'm a bit cautious to say this, because between what endpoints there was TLS can be an important question.

Comment: @SiTiVogl, the bigger problem is that you don't know if you are communicating with gmail or somebody in the middle. So this optional stuff only helps halfway through and creates a false sense of security IMO.

Answer (score 1):

`enable_starttls_auto` in itself does not protect you because a man in the middle can pretend to be gmail and let you connect only with plaintext, steal your password and access your email.

As to how to enforce it - either use what Gabor Lengyel suggested - normal TLS port. Or set `enable_starttls` which works and should show up in rails documentation at some point [#44096](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/44096). See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70429344/520567